# Creating Timestamp in Google Workflow YAML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

Trying to create a file output with date extension yyy-mm-dd etc.  Cloud workflow does not have the date format functions of bigquery.
Closet I could get is `${time.format(sys.now())}`, but that provides a timestamp.
Any way to parse to required format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mean a date extension in this format yyyy-mm-dd (your question says yyy-mm-dd).

`${time.format(sys.now())}` is giving me a timestamp like this:
2022-10-22T18:39:05.570539Z

With the [text.substring()](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/text/substring) function `${text.substring(time.format(sys.now()), 0, 10)}` I'm getting this string:
2022-10-22

Comment: How can we do current date - 1 day?